# Class type parameter based on subset of constructor parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, generic-type-parameters

I have a class that has a type parameter, `C`:

```ts
import { EventEmitter } from "events";

interface ClientData {
    a: string;
    b?: string;
}

interface ClientOptions {
    b?: string;
}

class Client<C extends ClientData> extends EventEmitter {

    constructor(clientData: C) {

        super();

        console.log(clientData.a); // string
        console.log(clientData.b); // string | undefined
    }
}

const client = new Client({
    a: "example",
    b: "placeholder"
});

/**
 * Client<{
 *    a: string;
 *    b: string;
 *}>
 */
type ClientType = typeof client;
```

The constructor of this class takes a parameter of type `ClientData`, where the input's type becomes the `C` type parameter. As seen by the `ClientType`, this works fine.

However, I need the `C` type to only contain a subset of the properties of `ClientData`, in this case, `ClientOptions`, and it needs to have a default value of `{}`:

```ts
class Client<C extends ClientOptions = {}> extends EventEmitter {

    constructor(clientData: C) {

        super();

        console.log(clientData.a); // Property 'a' does not exist on type 'C'
        console.log(clientData.b); // string | undefined
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the `clientData` parameter in the constructor will no longer have the `a` property from `ClientData`. Since constructors can't have type parameters, how can I have `clientData` be of type `ClientData`, but also make sure the `C` type extends `ClientOptions` with a default of `{}`? All properties of `ClientOptions` are optional and present in `ClientData`.

Answer (score 0):

Make the properties optional by using [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype):

```
class Client<C extends Partial<ClientData>> extends EventEmitter {

    constructor(clientData: C) {

        super();

        console.log(clientData.a); // string
        console.log(clientData.b); // string | undefined
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to make both `a` and `b` optional, I need `a` to be a required string